# React Loading a Dynamic Template using JSX & ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm pretty new to React, coming from an angular world. I have a scenario where I need to dynamically load a component give a searchType prop. The end user will have a dropdown of searchTypes they can pick from, this prop is passed in after they click the submit button.

I have a **SearchResults** component defined, which *should* dynamically load the appropriate component depending on the value of `this.props.searchType.name`

```
import React, { findDOMNode, Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Material from './Material'; // Material Search Results Component
import Vendor from './Vendor'; // Vendor Search Results Component

export default class SearchResults extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }


  // searchType = {
  //  name: 'Material',
  //  id: 'MATERIAL'
  // }

  render() {
    const { searchType, items, itemsCount } = this.props;

    var ComponentName = searchType.name;

    return (
      <div className='row'>
        <h1>Search Results ({items.length}/{itemsCount})</h1>
        <ComponentName items={items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SearchResults.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};
```

Now, this seems to partially work as when using the React Dev Tools in chrome I can see the  provider/component show up in the DOM.. but it doesn't render.

I'm just not sure where to go next from here, or if i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use a string instead of the actual class. I think you want something like this:

```js
var searchTypes = {
  Material,
  Vendor,
};

// ...

    var Component = searchTypes[searchType.name];

    return (
      <div className='row'>
        <h1>Search Results ({items.length}/{itemsCount})</h1>
        <Component items={items} />
      </div>
    );
```

Here's a [simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/hx1pjqpm/).

Comment: thanks this works perfectly.. One other thing i didn't mention as it was going to be the next step in this code is dynamically loading the Components ... `import ComponentName from './' + ComponentName;` or maybe if there is a way to extend those various components off a base class and import the entire base class and all its children? Either way, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: `import` declarations are static, so you can't do it that way. Eventually there'll be a dynamic module loader. For now you could dynamically generate `import` declarations as part of a build step. You could also create a module that imports and re-exports (in some fashion) all of the components, then import that into this component.

Comment: Actually I ended up doing an import * as Templates and then in the constructor I iterate over it and push to search types seems to work?

Comment: If you have a module that exports each of the search type components, sure. In that case I don't think you need to iterate it and copy to some other var though -- you can just do `Templates[searchType.name]` at that point, right?

Comment: Good point. I'll settle for putting all the various template classes into one file and load it instead of seper are files

Comment: You could have them in separate files, and have a module (let's call it `components`) that imports and exports them all. E.g. `import Material from './material'; import Vendor from './vendor'; export default {Material, Vendor};` Then in the component you illustrated here, `import Components from './components'; /* ... */ var Component = Components[searchType.name];`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a switch statement.

```
render() {
  //...
  var component;

  switch(searchType.name){
    case "material":
      component = <Material items={items} />
    case "vendor":
      component = <Vendor items={items} />
  }

  return (
    //...

    {component}
  )
}
```